# Database on client server android

Tags: java, android, performance, client-server

I am developing a simple client server application in Android, although I have a doubt. I will  save the data from app at server, and the app will need access them. I would like to know what's the best approach to manage data; Using two databases, one in the server and another in the smartphone (It will need synchronization), or only one at server (All requests will have to go to server) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, frankly speaking, it *depends on the kind of data* you are handling.

If your data is totally dynamic and varies at short intervals of time, you should always be querying the server.

On the other hand, if your data is relatively static and remains same over longer periods of time, it would be wise to cache the data in your local database, instead of querying it again and again from the server.

Another thing you have to keep in mind is the size of the data. If the data is really very large and you are storing it in your local database, then you need to clear the old data after a certain interval to make sure that your app is not eating up your memory.

Comment: What about performance requesting several times the data from server?

Comment: Well, requesting data from the server would be running on an AsyncTask, so your UI won't have any lag, if you are wondering about that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. Manage very large databases in the app is not the appropriate way (because the app will be very large after a while). You should store all of your data on the server and use SQLite in the app for cache only, but do not cache everything, just the data that don't change often.

Comment: What about performance requesting several times the data from server?

Comment: It also depends on the size of the data and the speed of connection.

Comment: Hard to tell exact performance comparison. If you also store your static data on the app and some "not so static" (which not changes often), it won't be a problem to request data several times.